# Flask was installed to the wrong path

Tags: python, windows, pip

I am using windows 11.

I saved the flask version I wanted to use in a requirements.txt.
Then I entered the following command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

After the installation I got the following warning:

> WARNING: The script flask.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\mica\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
> Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location

The problem is that I can't run any commands with flask. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Add that directory to your system or user PATH: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/